# ZF3 development of RestAPI: handling Post request for

Tags: zend-framework3

I am new to Zf3, and developing Email Restful API.

having difficulties in handling request. I can't get POST parameters.i think there is some problem in module.config.php > 'router'

**Questions** 
1 How can I get POST variables from request. 
2 I found it when I request page (using Postman) 
    - if I passes ID, controller call get($id) method  
    - if I POST variables controller calls Create($data) function.

--is this always the case ? and is it good to write zendEmail code inside create($data) method
.

**bwsmail controller**

(create function)

```
    public function create($data)  
    {
        echo $this->getRequest()->getPost('id', "no value");
              // Output
              // this returns no value

        echo $this->getRequest();
              // Output
              //POST http://localhost:8080/bwsmail/mail?id=123456789 HTTP/1.1
              //Cookie: PHPSESSID=p5i7o8lm2ed0iocdhkc8jvos01
              //Cache-Control: no-cache
              //Postman-Token: ccaf5b37-02a2-4537-bf3f-c1dc419d8ceb
              //User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.6.1
              //Accept: */*
              //Host: localhost:8080
              //Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
              //Content-Length: 0
              //Connection: keep-alive


         $response = $this->getResponseWithHeader()->setContent( __METHOD__.' create new item of data :<b>'.'</b>');
         return $response;
}
```

module.config.php (route)

```
'bwsmail' => [
            'type' => Literal::class,
            'options' => [
                'route' => '/bwsmail',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\BwsMailController::class,
                ]
            ],
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => [
                                'mail' => [
                                    'type' => 'segment',
                                    'options' => [
                                        'route' => '/mail[/:id]',
                                        'constraints'=>
                                        [
                                            'id' => '[0-9a-zA-Z]+',
                                        ],
                                        'defaults' => [
                                            'controller' => Controller\BwsMailController::class,
                                        ]
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
             ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `BwsMailController` extends `AbstractController` or `AbstractRestfulController` you can simply: `$this->params()->fromRoute()` or `->fromQuery()` if you're using a get string. For example:

```
$routeParamId = $this->params()->fromRoute('id', null);
```

This gets the parameter `id` as it is defined in the route configuration. If it's not set, it will default to `null`.

If you have a GET url, something like: `site.com/mail?id=123`, then you do:

```
$getParamId = $this->params()->fromQuery('id', null); // sets '123' in var
```

More options are available, have a good read of [the routing documentation](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-router/routing/).